# Static property access with php

Tags: php

I have been playing with namespaces and have a singleton that I pass around. It holds task specific configuration data.

singleton:

```
namespace Liberry\Core;

use Liberry\Utilities\Database;

    finaL class JobConfig
    {
        public static $scriptName;
        private static $instance;
        private static $database;
        private $incremental = false;
        private $incName;
        private $config;

        private function __construct()
        {

        }

        private function __clone()
        {

        }

        public static function getInstance($jobName = null, Database $database = null)
        {
            self::$database = $database ?: new Database();

            if (!is_object(self::$instance)) {
                if (!isset(self::$scriptName) && is_null($jobName)) {
                    throw new \Exception("Job name cannot be null");
                }
                self::$instance = new JobConfig();
                self::$scriptName = $jobName;
            }
            return self::$instance;
        }
    }
```

I have a `Files.php` class that has a save method. In this method I need the `JobConfig.php` static property `$scriptName`. Here is the class that tries to use this property.

```
namespace Liberry\Utilities;

use Liberry\Core\JobConfig;

class File
{
    private $database;
    private $config;

    public function __construct(JobConfig $conf, Database $database = null)
    {
        $this->database = $database ?: new Database();
        $this->config = $conf;
    }

    public function saveFile($data)
    {
//        $script =  $this->config::$scriptName -- THIS DOES NOT WORK
//        echo $script . "\n";
        $map = array(
            'content' => $data,
            'name' => $this->config->getFileName(),
            'sentByScript' => JobConfig::$scriptName,
            'enteredDT' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        );
        $this->database->insert('files', $map)->runQuery();
    }
}
```

My question is that if I'm passing an instance through the `construct()` method why cant I access it like `$this->config::$scriptName`? I am using php 5.5.9 ubuntu 14.04 Thanks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A static variable is essentially a global variable, i.e. unlike instances, there can be only one of it. So if you need to access a static variable, you don't need to pass instances of the class around. Simply access it directly like this:

```
JobConfig::$scriptName
```

Answer (score 0):

The :: operator is being used for is useful to refer to functions and variables in base classes or to refer to functions in classes that have not yet any instances.

In your case, you pass instance of JobConfig